# Comparing a string that includes wildcard "*" with a set of strings using regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex

I have a standard set of string literals as below:

```
actions = "GetClass ModifyClass DeleteClass ListObjects"
```

Now when I give an input string 'GetClass', my output should be 'GetClass'.

If I give an input as 'Get*', my output should be 'GetClass'.

If I give input as '*Class', my output should be a list that includes 'GetClass','ModifyClass' and 'DeleteClass'.

If the input string is '*Objects', my output should just be 'ListObjects'.

An input like 'Get','Class','Obj' should not give any of the four string literals as they don't specify them completely.

How can I use regular expression functions like match, compare to get this result. Please help. Note that I am using c++ for my code.

I had tried doing this like this:

```
boost::regex re("^"+input+"$");
while (boost::regex_search(actions, match, re) {
    //Push 'match' into the output list
    actions = match.suffix().str()
```

Please suggest the corrections. Thanks.

My code after changes suggested in comments looks like this

```
std::string wildcard("*");
std::osstringstream strStream;
for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
    if (input.compare(i, 1, wildcard) {
        strStream << "\\S";
    }
    strStream << wildcard
}
boost::regex re(strStream.str());
while (boost::regex_search(actions, match, re) {
    //Push 'match' into the output list
    actions = match.suffix().str()
}
```

Comment: Replace `"*"` with `"\\S*"`. Do not use `^` and `$`

Comment: Why not use `std::regex`?

Comment: @Kerndog73 Just a choice. I could have used std::regex as well. Is there an advantage to use std::regex over boost.

Comment: The main advantage is not having to haul boost into your project

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your suggestions. I will make the change and test.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your suggestions did work fine. Thanks for that.

Comment: You can post the resulting code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Does this need any special handling if we just input '*', because my machine just get stuck, probably due to infinite looping, not sure.

Comment: Add the code to the question please.

Comment: I am facing issue in case my input is say "*List". This should fail to match any entry, but it gives me an output entry as "List". Similary "*Delete" gives "Delete" back. @WiktorStribiżew any suggestions here.

Comment: So, what is the meaning of `*` in your case? `*` usually stands for any 0 or more chars. If you need to match 1 or  more, use `\\S+`

Comment: Here in my case if I give an input like "*elete" should not match because the string literal is DeleteClass, not just Delete. "*elete" gives me output as Delete.